# How to get max value from SQLite table column and return it to variable in MainActivity. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

1. Created the table in **DBHelper.java**:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_WORKOUT + "("
           + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
           + KEY_WONUMBER + " integer,"
           + KEY_WONAME + " text,"
           + KEY_WODESCRIPTION + " text,"
           + KEY_WOICON + " text,"
           + KEY_WOCOLOR + " text" + ")");}
   ```
2. In MainActivity.java  **onCreate** will be created some **OBJECTS**, that will be shown according to numbers from column KEY_WONUMBER of TABLE_WORKOUT
3. Need to find max value in KEY_WONUMBER and give it to variable in MainActivity.java and set next number for the next **OBJECT**
4. Trying to do it like this:

   ```
       public String getMaxNumber(){
       SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor c = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_WORKOUT, new String[]
               {"MAX("+DBHelper.KEY_WONUMBER+")"},
               null, null, null, null, null);

       StringBuffer buffer;
       if(c.getCount()>0){
           c.moveToFirst();
           String max_id=c.getString(0);
           buffer.append(max_id);
       }

       c.close();
       db.close();
       return buffer.toString();
   }
   ```
5. Getting next mistakes in raws:

   public String getMaxNumber(){    -   *';' expected*

   return buffer.toString();        -   *cannot return a value from a method with void result type

As a newbie in Android need your help to solve that problem

Comment: The first error is probably caused by a mistake earlier in your code and not on that line, the other is probably because of the first. I also wonder why you read a string when the query returns an integer?

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong in earlier code. Tere is only this before 


`@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);`

Comment: And **that** code is wrong, there is a } missing at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public String getMaxNumber(){ - ';' expected

You are missing a closing **`}`**. However fixing that then introduces *buffer may not have been initialized* error as you just have `StringBuffer buffer;` So attempting to append to it would result in a null pointer exception. You need to initialise buffer e.g. by using `StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");`

> return buffer.toString(); - *cannot return a value from a method with void result type

This is a result of the missing closing **`}`**. see above how this error is replaced by another.

## Fixes

Consider the following code and the comments therein :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        Log.d("MAXNUMBER", getMaxNumber());
    } //<<<<<<<<<< FIX 1 closes the onCreate method

    public String getMaxNumber () {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_WORKOUT, new String[]
                        {"MAX(" + DBHelper.KEY_WONUMBER + ")"},
                //{"COALESCE(MAX(" + DBHelper.KEY_WONUMBER + "),0)"}, //Alternative will return 0 instead of null if no rows

        null, null, null, null, null);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(""); //FIX2 initialize buffer by adding buffer = new StringBuffer("")
        if (c.moveToFirst()) { // moveToFirst will return false if no row to move to so no need to check row count
            String max_id = c.getString(0);
            buffer.append(max_id); //FIX 1 introduces might not have been inittialized (buffer hasn't been inittialized)
        }
        c.close();
        db.close(); // can be inefficient to keep on opening and closing the database
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

This returns (when no rows have been inserted) :-

```
D/MAXNUMBER: null
```

- see commented out query which uses COALESCE to return 0 rather than null in the returned string if you prefer to not have to handle null.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX("+DBHelper.KEY_WONUMBER+") FROM "+DBHelper.TABLE_WORKOUT,null) method instead of db.query()